# audio in keynote stopped working

Tags: audio, keynote

I have a presentation with a video that I've been using for some time, but now there is no sound with the video. The original video unembedded in keynote still has sound. I have checked all the settings within "format movie" etc. and can't find anything amiss.

OS is 13.0, keynote is version 12.2.1 (7035.0.161)

Comment: I'd try updating the OS first. The initial release of 13 [13.0.1] was buggy as all heck.] Current is 13.2.1

Comment: Yeah, it's working again now.